# What is the probability that at least 1 passenger will get off the bus at each stop?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are 20 passengers in a bus. They will randomly get off the bus in the next 3 stations $ S_1, S_2, S_3 $. What is the probability that at least one passenger will get off the bus at each of the stations? (this implies that 0 passengers could get off at a station)

Comment: Have you heard of inclusion-exclusion?  Consider the three events: $A_1,A_2,A_3$ where $A_i$ is the event that noone gets off at stop $i$.  What does $Pr(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)$ represent in this scenario then?  How might you calculate it?  How do you use this related calculation to find the probability you were originally after?

Comment: Alternatively, if you know something about Stirling numbers, the problem type this is falls under one of the cases in [the twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Surjective_functions_from_N_to_X) for a more direct solution but requires more theory to understand.

Comment: I have also reached at that same point, but I'm having trouble calculating $ P\left(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3\right) $, which is the reason I asked the question. After that I know i can just do $ 1 - P $ and I have my answer.

Comment: I direct you to my very first sentence again.  Have you heard of [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)?

Comment: No, but I just did. It still seems hard for me to see what is $ P(A_1 \cap A_2) $ etc. How should I go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Major hints and problem setup:**

Consider the three events $A_1,A_2,A_3$ where $A_i$ represents the event that noone gets off at stop $i$.

We have then the probability we are interested in originally is $Pr(A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap A_3^c)=1-Pr(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)$

Using [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) this simplifies further:

> $=1-Pr(A_1)-Pr(A_2)-Pr(A_3)+Pr(A_1\cap A_2)+Pr(A_1\cap A_3)+Pr(A_2\cap A_3)-Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)$

Each term in the above should be straightforward to calculate.

> For example $Pr(A_1\cap A_2)$ represents the probability that noone gets off at stop one and noone gets off at stop two, i.e. everyone gets off at stop three.  Assuming that each person gets off uniformly and independently at random from one another at one of the three stops, each person individually has a $1$ in $3$ chance to get off at the third stop and this needs to occur for each of the twenty people so this occurs with probability $\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdots \cdot \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3^{20}}$.  The other terms are calculated similarly.

Comment: Oh you just made me realise that *all of them* have to get off the bus eventually. For some reason I thought that it was a valid possibility for 0 people to get off the bus, even after the 3rd stop. This helps a lot, thanks.

Comment: Part 1:

I was working on this again and while searching around I found this:
I can turn this problem into these symbols -> $ * $ and $ | $ in a row, where the amount of $ * $ is 20 and the amount of $ | $ is $ 3-1=2 $. Then all the combinations would be the ways to place those 2 $ | $ in $ 20+1=21 $ spots with no restrictions (they could go at the same spot) which is $ 21^2 $. This means if both $ | $ end up in the first spot, this means 0 passengers at $ S_1 $ and 0 at $ S_2 $ (and 20 at $ S_3$). So I have $ N(Ω) = 21^2 $.

Comment: Part 2:

Now I'm searching how many combinations there are in which at least one passenger is in each stop.This means we don't allow any of the $ | $ to be at the first and last spots (would mean first stop has no passengers, and last spot, respectively). So the first $ | $ has $ 21-2=19 $ available spots.Then this spot should not be available for the next $ | $. So $ 18 $ spots for it. Which means the $ N($at least one for each stop$)=19\cdot18 $. So the probability is $ \frac{19\cdot18}{21^2} $

Can you elaborate if this is correct? It's the simplest and most understandable for me.Thanks

Comment: Example:
$ ****|****************| $ would mean 4 passengers at $ S_1 $, 16 at $ S_2 $ and 0 at $ S_3 $

Comment: @gspoon be careful.  Although you could indeed describe your sample space like that using stars and bars, you will make a big mistake in doing so as the outcomes described are no longer equally likely to occur.  Consider a smaller example of two people and two stations.  Equivalently two coinflips in sequence.  There are three outcomes but the outcome of both people at the first stop (ie two heads flipped in a row) occurs with probability 1/4, not 1/3

Comment: Similarly, the outcome of 7at first stop, 7 at second and 6 at third is *much* more likely to occur than the outcome of 1 at first, 1 at second, and 18 at third, despite being counted the same number of times in stars and bars

Comment: It is similar to how when playing the lottery how you can choose to think of it as having two outcomes, you either win or you lose, but the probability of winning is far from being 1/2.  Number of favorable outcomes divided by total number of outcomes equals the probability is only valid when the outcomes are equally likely to occur.

Comment: What you said means that only passenger $P_1$ getting off at $S_1$ is different than only $P_2$ getting off at $S_1$ though, right? Because the problem is asking only for the number of people, not who is getting off where. Which would make all the outcomes equally likely, just like the stars and bars?

Comment: The question did not technically specify in what way the passengers decide to get off, it just said "randomly." The most common interpretation of that though is as I did above in my answer, that each person individually decides whether they will get off at stop 1 2 or 3. In that interpretation, stars and bars is not useful and will give the wrong answer. Just because the event we are interested in only refers to number of people at each stop, this does not suddenly make the outcomes counted by stars and bars equally likely. They are still *not* equally likely and aren't the right approach.

Comment: Again, I encourage you to examine the example with two people and two stops more closely.  Imagine the first person flips a coin.  If heads, he gets off at the first stop.  Otherwise he gets off at the second.  The second person does the same thing.  Stars and bars would tell you there are three possibilities, both in the first, both in the second, or one in each.  Using a more traditional or rigorous approach though shows us that both in the first occurs with probability 0.25, one in each with probability 0.5 and both in second with probability 0.25.

Comment: I can see your point on the question not being specific and why you'd think this is how they get off the bus. But this is the exact way I found it from my professor and it amounts to half the grades of a question, from an exam with 3 questions. About your point, I think he intentionally didn't say that each passenger has an equal probability to get off at each station, so we would think of the problem the way I did. This, and the fact that it doesn't amount to a big portion of the test, made me think that the right approach is the one I chose, which seems to me to be the "easiest" one.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it again, I can now see why your answer is correct.
What I'm thinking now is how to find $P(A_i)$ and $P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3)$. For any $P(A_i)$ I just say that each passenger has a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance to not get off at $S_i$ , so $P(A_i) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{20}$, right? Then $P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A_3)$ is $0$ ? I'm not sure.